# SQL query equal fields different fields

Tags: sql

In my DB, I have 3 fields:

```
property_id
e_id
name
```

I need to know `registers` with the same `property_id` and name but different `e_id`.

Comment: What are registers?

Comment: @TabAlleman I'm guessing that the three columns collectively describe a register.

Comment: e_id is primary key, I don't get it...

Comment: Please improve the question by providing sample data and expected results.  as well as defining what a register is and Tagging which RDBMS & version (Oracle, mySQL, Postgresql, SQL Server 2016, ) you are using  a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) often helps describe what you're trying to accomplish.  The expected results tell us what fields you are looking to return and help clarify the logic needed to get to the desired results given your sample data.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate over properties and names and then count the number of distinct `e_id` values:

```
SELECT property_id, name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY property_id, name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e_id) > 1
```

Note that if `property_id` were a primary key uniquely determining the name, then we could aggregate by property alone.

Comment: You're missing `name` in the group by, but I bet there's a duplicate to this question on the site already.

Answer (score 0):

A Self join can be used to find matches on property and name; and by using a < on E_ID we ensure we only get 1 record match and not its inverse.

[Rextester Working Example](http://rextester.com/IGWL52232)

Assuming

1. mySQL; but this has no specific DB logic so it should work on almost any engine.
2. A Register is a record in the table with those 3 unique fields.

So

```
SELECT A.Property_ID, A.E_ID, A.Name, B.E_ID
FROM Tbl A
INNER JOIN tbl B
 on A.Property_ID = B.Property_ID
and A.Name = B.Name
and A.E_ID < B.E_ID
```

Data:

```
+-------------+------+-------+---+
| Property_ID | E_ID | Name  |   |
+-------------+------+-------+---+
|           1 |    1 | A     |   |
|           1 |    1 | A     |   |
|           2 |    1 | Test  |   |
|           2 |    2 | Test  |   |
|           3 |    2 | Test2 |   |
|           3 |    3 | Test3 |   |
|           4 |    4 | Test4 |   |
|           5 |    5 | Test5 |   |
|           6 |    7 | Test6 |   |
|           6 |    6 | Test6 |   |
+-------------+------+-------+---+
```

Gives:

```
+-------------+------+-------+---+
|           2 |    1 | Test  | 3 |
|           6 |    6 | Test6 | 7 |
+-------------+------+-------+---+
```

BUT NOT:

```
+-------------+------+-------+---+
|             |      |       |   |
|           2 |    2 | Test  | 1 |
|           6 |    7 | Test6 | 6 |
+-------------+------+-------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e_id, property_id, name 
FROM  table1 
WHERE  e_id in (SELECT e_id 
                FROM table1 
                GROUP BY e_id  
                HAVING count(e_id) > 1)
```

Comment: I don't believe this will return the desired results: try it out here: http://rextester.com/YCMSOF94139

Comment: Just tested my query using your url and it did what I expect it to do.  Unless I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use group by clause here 
your query will be

```
select property_id, e_id , name from your_table groupby e_id
```

Comment: test it out http://rextester.com/XCOUD86115  you'll see that this doesn't return the proper results.  Maybe you're trying to rely on the extended mySQL group by.  but without specifying that in your answer it's hard to tell.

Comment: yeah, xQbert is right!